# Implementing objects from one class in another

Tags: c++, class, object, operator-overloading

I've been having trouble trying to implement objects from class `Cart_Vector` in class `Cart_Point`. My compiler has been listing the following errors and I can't seem to fix them:

> friend Cart_Point operator+(const Cart_Point&p1,const Cart_Vector&v1);
>   'Cart_Vector' does not name a type
>
> Cart_Point operator+(const Cart_Point&p1, const Cart_Vector&v1)
>   'Cart_Vector' does not have a type
>
> x = p1.x + v1.x; request for member 'x' in 'v1', which is of non-class
>   type 'const int'
>
> y = p1.y + v1.y; request for member 'y' in 'v1', which is of non-class
>   type 'const int'
>
> return Cart_Vector(x,y); 'Cart_Vector' was not declared in this scope

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>


using namespace std;

class Cart_Point
{
public:

        double x;
        double y;

        friend class Cart_Vector;

    Cart_Point (double inputx, double inputy);
    friend Cart_Point operator<<(const Cart_Point&p1, const Cart_Point&p2);
    friend Cart_Point operator+(const Cart_Point&p1,const Cart_Vector&v1);
    friend Cart_Point operator-(const Cart_Point&p1,const Cart_Point&p2);

    double Cart_distance(Cart_Point, Cart_Point);


};

Cart_Point::Cart_Point(double inputx, double inputy)
{
   x = inputx;
   y = inputy;
}

double Cart_Point::Cart_distance(Cart_Point p1, Cart_Point p2)
{
    double distance = (sqrt( pow(p1.x - p2.x,2) + pow(p1.y - p2.y,2) ));
    return distance;

//returns distance between p1 (point 1) and p2 (point 2)
}

Cart_Point operator<<(const Cart_Point&p1, const Cart_Point&p2)
{
    cout << "p1:(" << p1.x << ", " << p1.y << ")" << endl;
    cout << "p2:(" << p2.x << ", " << p2.y << ")" << endl;
    return p1,p2;
//this function should just print each point
}

Cart_Point operator+(const Cart_Point&p1, const Cart_Vector&v1)
{
    double x,y;

    x = p1.x + v1.x;
    y = p1.y + v1.y;

    return Cart_Point(x,y);

//this function should make a new Cart_Point 
}

Cart_Point operator-(const Cart_Point&p1, const Cart_Point&p2)
{
    double x,y;
    x = p1.x- p2.x;
    y = p1.y - p2.y;

    return Cart_Vector(x,y);

//this function should make a new Cart_Vector
}

    class Cart_Vector
{
public:
    double x; //x displacement of vector
    double y; //y displacement of vector

    Cart_Vector(double inputx, double inputy);

    friend Cart_Vector operator*(const Cart_Vector&v1, double d);
    friend Cart_Vector operator/(const Cart_Vector&v1, double d);
    Cart_Vector operator<<(const Cart_Vector&v1);

    friend class Cart_Point;
};

Cart_Vector::Cart_Vector(double inputx, double inputy)
{
    x = inputx;
    y = inputy;
}

Cart_Vector operator*(const Cart_Vector&v1, double d)
{
    double x,y;
    x = v1.x*d;
    y = v1.y*d;

    return Cart_Vector(x,y);

//this function should make a new Cart_Vector
}

Cart_Vector operator/(const Cart_Vector&v1, double d)
{
  double x,y;
  if (d == 0)
  {
      x = v1.x;
      y = v1.y;
  }

  x = v1.x/d;
  y = v1.y/d;

  return Cart_Vector(x,y);

//this function should make a new Cart_Vector and dividing by zero creates v1
}

Cart_Vector Cart_Vector::operator<<(const Cart_Vector&v1)
{
    cout <<"v1: <" << v1.x << ", " << ">" << endl;
    return v1;

//this function should just print v1
}


//TestCheckpoint1.cpp file below
int main()
{

//I haven't finished the main function to test all the functions yet
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Define `Cart_Vector` before `Cart_Point`, since the latter uses the former, but not vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

split your code in different files but your implementation of operator << is wrong , consider following code , its just a hint to help

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>


using namespace std;


class Cart_Vector
{
public:
double x; //x displacement of vector
double y; //y displacement of vector

Cart_Vector(double inputx, double inputy);

friend Cart_Vector operator*(const Cart_Vector&v1, double d);
friend Cart_Vector operator/(const Cart_Vector&v1, double d);
friend std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& out,const Cart_Vector&v1);

friend class Cart_Point;
};


Cart_Vector::Cart_Vector(double inputx, double inputy)
{
    x = inputx;
    y = inputy;
}

Cart_Vector operator*(const Cart_Vector&v1, double d)
{
    double x,y;
    x = v1.x*d;
    y = v1.y*d;

    return Cart_Vector(x,y);

//this function should make a new Cart_Vector
}

Cart_Vector operator/(const Cart_Vector&v1, double d)
{
  double x,y;
  if (d == 0)
  {
      x = v1.x;
      y = v1.y;
  }

  x = v1.x/d;
  y = v1.y/d;

  return Cart_Vector(x,y);

//this function should make a new Cart_Vector and dividing by zero creates v1
}

 std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Cart_Vector&v1)
{
   out <<"v1: <" << v1.x << ", " << ">" << endl;
    return out;

//this function should just print v1
}


class Cart_Point
{
public:

        double x;
        double y;

        friend class Cart_Vector;

    Cart_Point (double inputx, double inputy);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out , const Cart_Point&p2);
    friend Cart_Point operator+(const Cart_Point&p1,const Cart_Vector&v1);
    friend Cart_Point operator-(const Cart_Point&p1,const Cart_Point&p2);

    double Cart_distance(Cart_Point, Cart_Point);


};

Cart_Point::Cart_Point(double inputx, double inputy)
{
   x = inputx;
   y = inputy;
}

double Cart_Point::Cart_distance(Cart_Point p1, Cart_Point p2)
{
    double distance = (sqrt( pow(p1.x - p2.x,2) + pow(p1.y - p2.y,2) ));
    return distance;

//returns distance between p1 (point 1) and p2 (point 2)
}





std::ostream&  operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Cart_Point&p1)
{
    // Since operator<< is a friend of the Cart_Point class, we can access Point's members directly.
    out << "p:(" << p1.x << ", " << p1.y << ")" << endl;

    return out;
//this function should just print each point
}

Cart_Point operator+(const Cart_Point&p1, const Cart_Vector&v1)
{
    double x,y;

    x = p1.x + v1.x;
    y = p1.y + v1.y;

    return Cart_Point(x,y);

//this function should make a new Cart_Point
}

Cart_Point operator-(const Cart_Point&p1, const Cart_Point&p2)
{
    double x,y;
    x = p1.x- p2.x;
    y = p1.y - p2.y;

    return Cart_Point(x,y);

//this function should make a new Cart_Vector
}


//TestCheckpoint1.cpp file below
int main()
{

Cart_Point point1(2.0, 3.0);

    std::cout << point1;


//I haven't finished the main function to test all the functions yet
    return 0;
}
```

[Wandbox :](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/odwjhiClxrP8DyWW)

Answer (score 0):

Cart_Vector and Cart_point need each other. So you need to implement these classes in separate header files. Do not forget include them. Also in here ;

```
Cart_Point operator-(const Cart_Point&p1, const Cart_Point&p2)
{
    double x,y;
    x = p1.x- p2.x;
    y = p1.y - p2.y;

    //return Cart_Vector(x,y);
    return Cart_Pointer(x,y);
//this function should make a new Cart_Vector
}
```

You can not access non-const elements of const object and you can not call non-const functions. You can pass these objects by value if you want it.

Comment: I guess there is a problem here  return Cart_Point (x,y) ;   shoule be correct

Comment: Yes, also this function can not return Cart_ Vector (x, y).

Answer (score 0):

Do yourself a favor and split your code in different files,at least one .h for Cart_Vector, one .h for Cart_Point, and one .cpp for the test script (main). You can correct this code to make it work (just swap the order of the two classes), if you correct other errors too, like in the overloading of the operator "-".

The point here is that if you start coding in this way, when you start programming complex projects you will find yourself in great difficulties. Coding one public (non-inner) class-per file is like applying Single Responsibility Principle for files too. I would say that also a file should have only one reason to change, and this has great benefits in **readability** and  when will you perform **version control**.